# Android Jsoup error unexpectendly stoppes app

Tags: java, android, html-parsing, jsoup

I had build in past an android app that i used Jsoup to parse some data from an html site. And it worked just FINE...

Now i started to build another app and i have used the same code, the same jsoup library, everything is the same between these projects but the only diference is the java version the new one is 1.7 the old one i dont remember and the eclipse version the new one is Juno and the past one i dont remember also...

If i run the new app i get an has stopped application unexpectandly...

If i run the app without the jsoup code it runs nice..

I tried to reopen the old app that was running in the past and and now the same problem as the new app.

Anybody got any idea what is going on... II can give any info that you would like....
Thnaks a lot...

Comment: what's the error you are getting in logcat before the termination ?

Comment: Thanks but i fixed it. I had to check the jsoup in preferences... Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks but i fixed it. I had to check the jsoup in preferences... Thanks again